# Trouble saving to S3 from Jenkins using Django

Tags: django, jenkins, amazon-s3, boto

I am running tests in Jenkins for a Django application, but received 403 errors when running the tests that upload to S3.  The values are exported as environment variables and accessed in the settings file with values.Value() (https://django-configurations.readthedocs.org/en/stable/values/).

```
# settings.py
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = values.Value()
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = values.Value()
```

My console output looks like this:

```
[EnvInject] - Injecting as environment variables the properties content 
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID='ABC123'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='blah'

[EnvInject] - Variables injected successfully.
```

...

```
+ python manage.py test
======================================================================
ERROR: test_document (documents.tests.DocTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Job/workspace/myapp/documents/tests.py", line 25, in setUp
    self.document.doc.save('test_file', File(f), save=True)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Job/workspace/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 89, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Job/workspace/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 51, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Job/workspace/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py", line 385, in _save
    key = self.bucket.get_key(encoded_name)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Job/workspace/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 192, in get_key
    key, resp = self._get_key_internal(key_name, headers, query_args_l)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Job/workspace/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 230, in _get_key_internal
    response.status, response.reason, '')
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
boto: DEBUG: path=/documents/test_file
boto: DEBUG: auth_path=/my-bucket/documents/test_file
boto: DEBUG: Method: HEAD
boto: DEBUG: Path: /documents/test_file
boto: DEBUG: Data: 
boto: DEBUG: Headers: {}
boto: DEBUG: Host: my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
boto: DEBUG: Port: 443
boto: DEBUG: Params: {}
boto: DEBUG: Token: None
boto: DEBUG: StringToSign:
HEAD


Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:02:36 GMT
/my-bucket/documents/test_file
boto: DEBUG: Signature:
AWS 'ABC123':RanDoM123#*$
boto: DEBUG: Final headers: {'Date': 'Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:02:36 GMT', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Authorization': u"AWS 'ABC123':RanDoM123#*$, 'User-Agent': 'Boto/2.38.0 Python/2.7.3 Linux/3.2.0-4-amd64'}
boto: DEBUG: Response headers: [('x-amz-id-2', 'MoReRanDom123*&^'), ('server', 'AmazonS3'), ('transfer-encoding', 'chunked'), ('x-amz-request-id', '3484RANDOM19394'), ('date', 'Sun, 13 Sep 2015 06:02:36 GMT'), ('content-type', 'application/xml')]
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------
```

Am I missing something important in order to upload files to S3 from Jenkins?  I'm having no issues on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Does your CORS configuration on this bucket have any restrictions per IP? For example, if `AllowedOrigin` specifies the IP, it could be one reason why it fails.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
```

I would also print out your `AWS` values on Jenkins for debugging, just to confirm that the correct values are being used in that environment.